# warning: mail() expects parameter 4 to be string

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the below code to send mail, but got the below error
Doesn't `mail()` take in arrays for headers?

```
Warning: mail() expects parameter 4 to be string, array given in ../email.php on line 16
```

code :

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'example@gmail.com';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: `Warning: mail() expects parameter 4 to be string, array given in ../email.php on line 16` simple answer

Comment: The error message is your answer! Read it. Or at least [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just started php for two days.  Got this code somewhere and trying to make it work, it was initially written in array and I thought it suppose to work with an array since it was written like this.  you are right I should've trust the manual.

Comment: why downvote? there is no reason to downvote . My Upvote for Justice.

Comment: mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) need `string $to`, `string $subject`, `string $message`, `string $headers`

if you want to use an array for the headers

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

else change your code in

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";
```

why `\r\n` (from [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation)?

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n) [...]
>   If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail
>   transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF
>   automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This
>   should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

side note use `"\r\n"` and not `'\r\n'`

Comment: Thank you, your solution works!
I've replaced $headers with implode(PHP_EOL, $headers)

Comment: @user2094220 `PHP_EOL` is not always set to `\r\n`. Use `"\r\n"` instead.

Comment: @SimoneNigro Yes, saw that and your answer is correct now. The comment was for OP.

Answer (score 4):

As the message says the 4th parameter (`$additional_headers`) should be a string. So you need to join the array elements:

```
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> String to be inserted at the end of the email header.
>
> This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). If outside data are used to compose this header, the data should be sanitized so that no unwanted headers could be injected.

Comment: I've replaced $headers with implode(PHP_EOL, $headers) as per @Simone Nigro advice. which I think is the same as the one you proposed, thank  you =)

Comment: @user2094220 Originally he proposed to use `PHP_EOL` which is wrong. `"\r\n"` should be used. See my comment below his answer too.

Comment: @user2094220 `implode(PHP_EOL, $headers)`  it's wrong!!! use `implode("\r\n", $headers)` . I'm sorry!

Comment: thanks all for the heads up, I've changed it to CRLF implode("\r\n", $headers)

Answer (score 3):

You make `$headers` to be a array, but it has to be a string! So just change these lines:

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

to this and concatenate the strings together:

```
$headers   = "";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
```